# Remote MySQLDump to backup Jira produces small file

Tags: backup, jira, mysql

I am using this command to try and remotely backup Jira:

mysqldump -h192.168.20.151 -uJiraSQLUser -p database > c:\my.sql

It connects, runs, but produces a 2mb file. We have a lot more data so wondering what could be going wrong here.

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This would probably work better on [SF]. That said, have you looked at my.sql to see if it leaves out tables or data? It's plain text, after all. Please [edit] your question to include some more information about what's in the file. Thanks for improving the question's reference value!

Comment: The .sql file appears to contain lots of... SQL stuff. Tables, lock tables, unlock tables, drop tables. Seems to go to "Dumping data for table <table>" Then issues LOCK TABLES, INSERT INTO, has a bit of information, then UNLOCK TABLES. The goes to another table. The data in between "Dumping data for table..." and the next "Dumping data for table..." is very small, just a few lines then goes to the next.